# Click on a notification receive Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: java, android, token

My app receive a notification. When I click on the notification, my app will launch a activity. The activity will invoke a `PopupWindow`, and then I receive this exception:

```
popWindow.showAtLocation(((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.root_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
context is the activity

04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.innereye.online/com.innereye.online.PassengerDetailActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2939)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2969)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5383)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:709)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:74)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1027)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:878)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:842)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at com.innereye.online.util.share.ShareUtil.showCustomizeShare(ShareUtil.java:100)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at com.innereye.online.state.OrderStateFinish.handle(OrderStateFinish.java:72)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at com.innereye.online.state.StateManager.handle(StateManager.java:150)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at com.innereye.online.PassengerDetailActivity$PlaceholderFragment.parseBundle(PassengerDetailActivity.java:480)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at com.innereye.online.PassengerDetailActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onResume(PassengerDetailActivity.java:436)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1543)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1894)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:466)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:455)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onPostResume(ActionBarActivity.java:115)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5317)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
04-02 07:56:26.014: E/AndroidRuntime(5480):     ... 12 more
```

---

public void onMessage(Context context, PushMessage msg) {
    super.onMessage(context, msg);
    sendNotification(context, msg, StateManager.StateDesc.FINISH_PUSH.toString(), PassengerDetailActivity.class);

### }

public void handle(Object obj, String para) {
    Order order = JSON.parseObject(para, Order.class);
    PassengerDetailActivity.PlaceholderFragment fragment = (PassengerDetailActivity.PlaceholderFragment)obj;
    fragment.stopTimer();
    fragment.stopLocationTimer();
    fragment.waitLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    fragment.mapLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    fragment.notifyMessageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String strPrice = "";
    fragment.phoneNumTextView.setText("");  ((PassengerDetailActivity)fragment.getActivity()).getmMenu().findItem(R.id.action_cancel).setVisible(false);
    ShareUtil.showCustomizeShare(fragment.getActivity(), null, strPrice, order.getHonorString());

### }

public static void showCustomizeShare(Context context, PlatformActionListener l, String priceInfo, String reduceInfo) {
    SharePopupWindow popWindow = new SharePopupWindow(context);
    popWindow.setPlatformActionListener(l);
    ShareModel shareModel = new ShareModel();
            shareModel.setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_title));        shareModel.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_content));
    shareModel.setImageUrl(context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_image_url));
    shareModel.setUrl(context.getResources().getString(R.string.share_url));
    shareModel.setPrice(priceInfo);
    shareModel.setReduce(reduceInfo);
    popWindow.initShareParams(shareModel);
    popWindow.showShareWindow();   popWindow.showAtLocation(((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.notify_message_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}

Comment: Can you add the relevant lines of code that produce this exception?